# React Redux Thunk trigger multiple actions on one call

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have an action which in turn must affect many other areas of my app state. In this case, when the user selects a website from a dropdown list, it must update many other components. I'm currently doing it like so:

```
setSelectedWebsite (websiteId) {
    // The core reason for this component
    this.props.setSelectedWebsite(websiteId);

    // Fetch all associated accounts
    this.props.fetchAllAccounts(websiteId)

    // Several other "side effect" calls here...
}
```

In this interest of making one component serve one purpose, this feels like a bad practice.

**What is the best practice for triggering multiple actions in one call from a component?**

Comment: what do u mean by multiple actions?What actually it means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

Your component's method:

```
setSelectedWebsite(websiteId){
    this.props.handleSetSelectedWebsite(websiteId) // this is a thunk
}
```

Your Redux file with action creators / thunks:

```
// this function is a thunk

export const handleSetSelectedWebsite = (websiteId) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setSelectedWebsite(websiteId))
    dispatch(fetchAllAccounts(websiteId))
}

// these function are action creators (or could be other thunks if you style them the same way as the thunk above)

const setSelectedWebsite = (websiteId) => {
    // your code
}

const fetchAllAccounts = (websiteId) => {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I'm already using redux-thunk. Is it best practice to put these dispatches into the action rather than calling them from the component?

Comment: @MattSaunders Yes. This way UI is separated from logic.

Answer (score 0):

For handling complex side effects in a redux application, I would recommend looking at using Redux Sagas. I have seen its usage grow in popularity on projects large and small, and for good reason.

With sagas, in the example you have provided, you can emit a single action from a function provided through `mapDispatchToProps` and let a saga take care of the rest. For example: (following example assumes flux standard actions)

```
//import redux connect, react, etc

class SiteSelector extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const id = this.props.id;

        return (
           <button onClick={ () => this.props.action(id)>Click Me</button>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    id: state.websiteId
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    action: (id) => dispatch(setSelectedWebsite(id))
})

export connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SiteSelector)
```

Now you can handle the action emitted from `setSelectedWebsite` in a saga like so:

```
//import all saga dependencies, etc 

export function* selectSite(action) {
  const id = action.payload.id
  yield put(Actions.selectWebsite(id))
  const results = yield call(Api.fetchAllAccounts, id)
  yield //do something complex with results
  yield //do something else...
  yield //and keep going...
}

// Our watcher Saga: spawn a new selectSite task every time the action from setSelectedWebsite is dispatched 
export function* watchForSiteSelection() {
  yield takeEvery('SITE_SELECTED_ACTION', selectSite)
}
```

For reference checkout the docs: [Redux Sagas](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm reluctant to add yet another layer to this. Is there nothing I can do with redux/redux-thunk natively?

Comment: @MattSaunders Yes thunk can do that. You would simply dispatch multiple actions in one async action creator. The syntax changes only slightly. If it's only this one component, you can also dispatch multiple actions in mapDispatchToProps. No reason to bother with sagas for this particular use case.